# asp.net core 2.0 not getting exact path of css or view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path, asp.net-core-2.0, nopcommerce-4.0

net core 2.0 and i have getting issue to getting full path as shown as given below if you have any idea please give me solution

```
 string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins"), "Demopath"), "Views"), "DemoViews"), "Views.cshtml");
```

From this i am getting this path

```
D:\ILYAS\\nop4.0\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\net461\Plugins\Demopath\Views\DemoViews\Views.cshtml
```

But i don't need `\bin\Debug\net461\`

becuase of this extra line i am not getting my CSS and view page 
Is any one have idea please inform me

thank you in advance

Comment: Not the answer just a tip: you can write down [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) with multiple parameters: `Path.Combine("One", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")`

Comment: It helpful to remove multiple path combine thnx @MikeBovenlander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString(), "Plugins", "MyDemo", "Content", "css", "style.css");
```

It'll work

Answer (score 2):

Path seems combining proper.
Look at path

```
Plugins\Demopath\Views\DemoViews\Views.cshtml
```

it seems merged proper.

Your issue at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

You can use store url instead of BaseDirectory or something else.

Or you can go to root directory to Nop.Web

or use direct path using `Server.MapPath("YourPath")`.

`Server.MapPath` is easy to use multiple time `Path.Combine`.

Comment: I tried this but its  support in .net core i have tried with different approach

Comment: No need of two answers, if you got another solution after posting a question, you should edit first one and add *edit* there only. you can *edit* your answer anytime.

Comment: @Div - Thanks, at that time I don't know that.